# ArangoDB - How to support case-insensitive n-gram index

Tags: arangodb

I have successfully created an n-gram analyzer linked to an ArangoSearch view. The document field being indexed contains mixed case string content, but I would like users to be able to run case-insensitive queries angainst it. There is not an option for case in the n-gram analyzer properties, so I'm wondering how to do this. An example query I'm running, is as follows:

"for doc in myview search analyzer(doc.field in tokens('some input text','myanalyzer'), 'myanalyzer') sort BM25(doc) desc return doc"

This does not (fully) match fields containing "Some Input Text" due to case. Does anyone have recommendations to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This ist possible since v3.8.0.

a new type of analyzer, pipeline, was introduced.

With this you can chain the effects of multiple analyzers together.

```
arangosh> var analyzers = require("@arangodb/analyzers");
arangosh> var a = analyzers.save("ngram_upper", "pipeline", { pipeline: [
........>   { type: "norm", properties: { locale: "en.utf-8", case: "upper" } },
........>   { type: "ngram", properties: { min: 2, max: 2, preserveOriginal: 
false, streamType: "utf8" } }
........> ] }, ["frequency", "norm", "position"]);
arangosh> db._query(`RETURN TOKENS("Quick brown foX", "ngram_upper")`).toArray();
```

Source: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/analyzers.html#pipeline